# Creating a data contract assembly

Tags: wcf

Can anyone tell me how to make a data contract assembly?

Answer (score 2):

- Create a class library project in your Visual Studio solution
- add the classes that contain the data contracts to that project
- compile everything
- reference that assembly from your service code and your client-side code

Such an assembly is just a regular class-library assembly - there's nothing magic or mysterious about it....

Answer (score 0):

Use [svcutil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751905.aspx)

1. svcutil /dataContractOnly {Service_Metadata_Location}
2. Add the generated code to a Library and compile
3. Suppose you have to generate code for Client Proxies which use the above DataContracts, use the /reference:{Assembly_Path} option of svcutil to reuse the types from the assembly.